# is it safe to put 175/65r15 winter tires on my 2002 Toyota Echo?

Tags: toyota, tires, winter

I want to put winter tires on my Echo.  Some are available from a Hyundai but they have a different diameter.  Will it be safe to use them?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What is the normal sized tires you are using?

Answer (score 1):

Your Echo takes 175/65R14 tires and the 175/65R15 tires you are considering are:

1. Not going to fit on your existing rims.  So you would need to buy new rims as well as new tires.
2. Unlikely to provide the needed clearance and will likely rub the wheel wells.

So no, you should not use this size tire with your Echo.